# Iterate through a nested array and resultSet

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv, resultset

I have a resultset which I get from a data table
Then I am exporting this to a CSV file. However, I have a bug in the way I am doing when it has many resultSets.

So usually when is less than 5000 I have the following format. Which my code works with.

```
[{"account"=>"123456","time"=>"16789524554","status"=>"active",...},{"account"=>"3845679","time"=>"16789524554","status"=>"deleted",...}]
```

But then when I have many items it separates by arrays. So it will be like

```
[{"account"=>"123456","time"=>"16789524554","status"=>"active",...},{"account"=>"3845679","time"=>"16789524554","status"=>"deleted",...},{..},{.....},[{"account"=>.....},{...},{...}]]
```

And because of this I get the error `` undefined method `values' for #<Array: ``

I am not sure how to change my code to address this issue. Especially that I am not sure how many items go per array.

my code

```
def to_file(items)
    CSV.open('my_file.csv', 'wb') do |file|
      file << items.first.keys
      items.each { |item| file << item.values }
    end
end
```

EDIT: Just to be clear I have an array in the following format

my_array = [{....},{....},[{...},{..}]]
It's a nested array with resultSet. How can I iterate though that?

Comment: Is it expected that the hashes are nested into arrays when has more than 5000 entries? And if so, why is that? Or would you consider it a bug? And if so, why don't you fix the method that generates the `items` array to return those hashes unnested?

Comment: @spickermann I am not sure if I can change the method that query the items. That comes from Dynamo. So I belive and I might be wrong because I did not debug much yet, but I think it's when it reaches the limit of items and I need to use [last_evaluated_key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/api/Aws/DynamoDB/Client.html#:~:text=%3Alimit%20(Integer)%20%E2%80%94%20The%20maximum%20number%20of%20items,Query%20and%20Scan%20in%20the%20Amazon%20DynamoDB%20Developer%20Guide.)

Answer (score 2):

This is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You shouldn't be trying to figure out how to iterate over the data when it is formatted that way, you should be trying to figure out *why* it's being formatted that way and fix *that*.

Assuming that you don't care to resolve the underlying issue, if you have data that looks like this:

```rb
[
  { foo: "bar" },
  [
    { bar: "baz" }
  ]
]
```

And you want it to look like this:

```rb
[
  { foo: "bar" },
  { bar: "baz" }
]
```

Then you should call [`flatten`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) on the object to recursively flatten it:

```rb
nested_array = [{foo: 'bar'}, [{bar: 'baz'}]]
=> [{:foo=>"bar"}, [{:bar=>"baz"}]]

flattened_array = nested_array.flatten
=> [{:foo=>"bar"}, {:bar=>"baz"}]
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this is a good approach. Although, I think my code is slower now comparing to iterating each item.

Comment: Yes, I would expect that it would be slower because you're recursively iterating over multiple arrays containing 5000 elements each. That's why I recommend you solve the underlying issue instead and fix the problem that is initially generating the object as a nested array.

Comment: thank you. I actually just figure out the issue. I am getting the data from DynamoDb which it has a limit of how many items you can query. After achieving this limit you need to call again sending a key to query from where you stop. After I get that value I was doing ``results << new_results``. Where results is an array holding the values of the previous call. So as you see I was appending an array inside of another array. What I am doing now is results.push(*new_result) which will just get the result set of the array ``new_result`` and add that to the current array ``result``

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do it's to iterate through each element and check if it's an array
Like

```
def to_file(items)
    CSV.open('my_file.csv', 'wb') do |file|
      file << items.first.keys
      items.each do |outer_array|
        if outer_array.is_a?(Array)
          outer_array.each do |inner_array|
             file << inner_array.values
          end
        else
          file << outer_array.values
        end
      end
    end
end
```